# Nodejs mssql and PreparedStatement, excute not getting called

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I have included the mssql module into our node configuration.  The version of node is: 0.12.0, mssql is version 2.1.1 by Patrik Simek.

I can connect to our database I have prepared a statement but execute never gets called.  Before the code is executed, I know that a connection is estabilished to the database.

```
//The client object contains the user name eg. "First Last"
var aryNames = objClient['usr'].split(" ");

if ( !(aryNames && aryNames.length) ) {
    return;
}
var strSQL = "SELECT" + 
             " MIN(EventID)" +
             ",MAX(EventID)" +
             ",MIN(EventTime)" +
             ",MAX(EventTime)" +
             ",FirstName" +    
             ",Surname" +
             " FROM" +
             " [Net2].[sdk].[EventsEx]" +
             " WHERE" +
             " CAST(EventTime AS Date) BETWEEN @bow AND @eow" +
             " AND FirstName=@firstname" +
             " AND Surname=@surname" +
             " GROUP BY" +
             " CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), EventTime, 102)" +
             ",FirstName" +
             ",Surname",                       
  objParams = {bow       : objClient['tk_bow']
              ,eow       : objClient['tk_eow']
              ,firstname : aryNames[0]
              ,surname   : aryNames[aryNames.length-1]},
  ps = new mssql.PreparedStatement();
ps.input("bow",       mssql.DateTime2);
ps.input("eow",       mssql.DateTime2);
ps.input("firstname", mssql.VarChar);
ps.input("surname",   mssql.VarChar);
ps.prepare(strSQL, function(err) {
  console.log("prepare");          
  if ( err ) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  ps.execute(objParams, function(err, recordset)     {                                               
    console.log("execute");
    console.log(err);
    console.dir(recordset);
    ps.unprepare(function(err) {
    });                                     
  });
});
```

When this code is executed, the debug statement prepare is displayed, but I never see the execute statement.

I've looked at numerous examples and I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my connection routine, this fixed it.

Comment: How did you modify it? What was wrong, and what fixed it?  C'mon, dude :)  I have problems with PreparedStatement leaking connections (mssql.close() does not close all open sockets and process hangs on exit) and am looking for possible related solutions, you have not shown your solution.

Comment: Also, consider that you shared your code, someone else provided an Answer that said what you said above.  Would you mark that Answer as Accepted?

Comment: I'm away at the moment out of the country away from computer will answer when I return next werk

Comment: I don't see the solution was ever shared and I seem to be hitting this same issue.  Can you please share the solution?

Comment: Sorry, this question was posted two years ago, I'm not even sure where I was and what I was doing back then.